# Dart / Flutter How to programmatically Filter ListBuilder based on Value in List

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I am thinking there are a few different ways to do this, but in Flutter, I need to filter out values from my list. The values are sts[index].type. I see all the records show correctly with this builder:

```
return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: sts == null ? 0 : sts.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: Container(
                child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DetailsDaily(site: sts[index]),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          sts[index].name,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
```

I tried an if / else to filter the values:

```
return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: sts == null ? 0 : sts.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if (sts[index].type == "SNTL") {
             //return the widget with only SNTL types
          }
```

However, I get an issue with needing to show a return... however, I only want the SNTL ones to show... not sure why that check wouldn't work?

I tried in my futurebuilder:

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                    .loadString('assets/stations-strings.json'),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    List<SnoTelSiteModel> sites =
                        parseJson(snapshot.data.toString());
                    for(var s in sites){
                      if(s.type == "SNTL"){
                        return SnotelList(sts: sites);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }),
```

However, it returns all my results...

My last try is to return a list with the values already filtered out, but I don't want that as I would like to control what TYPE is shown in the screen in the future.

What am I doing wrong in my if/else that these are not showing?

Comment: Why not pass filtered `sts` to the `ListView.builder`? i.e. `final sntlList = sts.where((i) => i.type == 'SNTL').toList();`. Use this `sntlList` instead of `sts` to construct listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simpler syntax to filter the list using `where`, for example:

```
  List<SnoTelSiteModel> sites;
  return sites.where((site) => site.type == 'SNTL').toList();
```

You can use a different type in future (or, of course, dynamically) to filter the list by different types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying that last night and got this error: The return type 'List<SnoTelSiteModel>' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by anonymous closure.

Comment: actually, this does work in my jsonparse return statement... i was wrong there:  return jsonList.where((site) => site.type == 'SNTL').toList(); I guess I could pass the type I want to it there.